# trying to step through code within lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I have a function that looks like this

```
 public void DoSomething(){
     var lockThis = new Object();
     lock(lockThis){
        //trying to step through code
     }
 }
```

So I place a breakpoint within lock(lockThis){...}.  In theory, only one thread is in the critical section at a time, but can't I step through?  It breaks at the first line of code within it, and it keeps hitting the same line.  The breakpoints behave just like outside the lock.

EDIT:  I should describe the environment.  This class and the method arewithin the middle tier DLL.  The method is called by a webservice in an ASP.NET application.  I am doing a stress test on the webservice which spawns multiple threads that call the above method.

Comment: Each thread is trying to lock a different object. Two threads can't lock the same lock at the same time, but these are different locks.

Answer (score 2):

Your Lock object should be share between different thread, in this case you create single instance for each thread and call.`

```
Object lockThis = new Object();
```

or (depends on your code)

```
static Obejct lockThis = new Object();
public void DoSomething()
{

   lock(lockThis)
   {
      //trying to step through code
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your second solution.  It is still behaving the same.  I edited the post to give a description of my environment.

Comment: As I said you should use same instance of object for locking, I don't know how you use this method. Do you use same instance of class or create new one each time?

Comment: Second one means Static object?

Comment: Yes.  I am using the second option.  Yes a new instance is created each time and I can't think of a way around it.  Static class AND static method will be the way to go?

Comment: Yes the static object should create only once, and it should be working